# Solving $x \equiv \frac{2^{4n} - 1}{5} \pmod {2^m}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Since $2^4 \equiv 16 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ then $2^{4n} \equiv (2^4)^n \equiv 1^n \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ so $\frac{2^{4n} - 1}{5} \in \mathbb{Z}$

> Let $m \in \mathbb{N}$. How can we find $x(n) = x \in \{0,1, \dots 2^m - 1 \}$ such that $x(n) \equiv \frac{2^{4n} - 1}{5} \pmod {2^m}$?

This is a little confusing since it isn't necessarily so that $\frac{2^{4n} - 1}{5} \equiv 5^{-1}(2^{4n} - 1) \pmod {2^m}$

Comment: I see where you are going here, but your question is worded somewhat peculiarly.  $\frac{2^{4n} -1}{5} \pmod{2^m}$ depends only on $n$ and $m$, but does not depend on $x$.  So, I suggest editing your question to eliminate the $x(n)$ syntax, and instead refer to $f(n,m) = \frac{2^{4n} -1}{5} \pmod{2^m}.$

Comment: As far as "...since it isn't necessarily so that $\frac{2^{4n} - 1}{5} \equiv 5^{-1}(2^{4n} - 1) \pmod {2^m}$":  I haven't checked whether this is true or not.  Assuming that it is true, I suggest that you [1] Identify precisely when the modular equivalence breaks down and [2] Break your work up into 2 cases, that you work separately, depending on whether the modular equivalence holds.

Comment: "since it isn't necessarily so that 24n−15≡5−1(24n−1)(mod2m)"  It most certainly *is* so!  As $5$ is coprime to $2^m$ there exists an integer $K$ so that $5K\equiv 1\pmod{2^m}$.  Thus if we ever have $5A\equiv 5B$ we can multiple both sides by $K$ to conclude $A \equiv B$.  So as $5\times \frac {2^{4n}-1}5 =2^{4n}-1$ we can multiple both sides but $5^{-1}$ to get $\frac {2^{4n}-1}5 = 5^{-1}(2^{4n} -1)$.

Comment: Note:  If $\frac ba\in \mathbb N$.  And if there exist a $k$ so that $ak\equiv 1 \pmod n$ (which is true if and only if $\gcd(a,n) = 1$)... then it will *always* be the case that $\frac ab \equiv ka \pmod n$.  We *can* use notation of $\frac 1a$ as though it were an integer and for the purpose of modulo arithmetic refer to the statement $\frac 1a \equiv k \pmod n$ as that $\frac 1a$ were an integer.  This is kosher and is sanctioned and ordained by your local number theorist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that it doesn't matter if we write our answer in any particular base, since base 2 is much more convenient than base 10 to answer this question. Otherwise, you'll need to look for a different answer.

It helps whenever working modulo a power of a prime, to think in terms of writing your numbers in that base. So for our case, we want to think in base $2$ since this is compatible modulo $2^m$, since this amounts to cleanly chopping off any higher digits which is unambiguous.

Specifically here, what we have looks suspiciously like a geometric series. Unfortunately, we can't quite simplify $\frac{2^{4n}-1}{5}=\frac{2^{4n}-1}{2^2+1}$ as a geometric series. But we can multiply by $\frac{2^2-1}{2^2-1}$ to make,

$$\frac{2^{4n}-1}{5} = 3 * \frac{2^{4n}-1}{2^4-1} = 3* (1+2^4+2^{4*2} + \cdots+ 2^{4*(n-1)})$$

Since we're in base $2$ we should really write $3=1+2$ and distribute. Since the digits are separated by 4 digits, there will be no carrying, so we get,

$$\frac{2^{4n}-1}{5} = 1+2+2^4+2^{4+1}+2^{4*2} + 2^{4*2+1} + \cdots + 2^{4*(n-1)}+ 2^{4*(n-1)+1}$$

Alternatively we could write this number in base $2$ since the pattern of digits is just $0011$ repeated exactly $n$ times as:
$$110011...00110011_2$$

Because this might not be in the range from $0$ and $2^m-1$, all we have to do now is remove all the higher digits which is no problem, since we simply check that the exponent is $m$ or greater and remove that term entirely, and we're done.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think is going on. $(2^{4n}-1)/5$ is an integer, because
$$\frac{2^{4n}-1}{5}=3\cdot \frac{16^n-1}{16-1}=3\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}16^i.$$
However, this integer may not be an element of $\{0,1,\ldots,2^m-1\}$ if $n$ is large compared to $n$. Note that $16^i\equiv 0\pmod{2^m}$ if $\lfloor i/4\rfloor\ge m$. So
$$\frac{2^{4n}-1}{5}=3\cdot\sum_{i=0}^{\min\{n-1,\lfloor m/4\rfloor -1\}}16^i\equiv \frac{16^{\min\{n,\lfloor m/4\rfloor\}}-1}{5}\pmod {2^m}$$
and that
$$0\le \frac{16^{\min\{n,\lfloor m/4\rfloor\}}-1}{5}\le \frac{2^m-1}{5}.$$
So this is the desired integer.